# How to write into file using echo with a predefined constant and a variable combined without spaces in batch?

Tags: batch

The following batch script should give an output without a space between the constant and the variable.

```
set /p _a="Enter :"
echo a %_a% >a.js
```

When the input is: `t`, the output in the file should be: `at` (without space between `a` and `t`).

Can anyone suggest a way this can be done?

Edit (from comment on answer by OP):

My real problem is that I need to put the variable after the character `!`. When I try to do that without the space in between, it doesn't work. For Example:

```
echo a!%_a% >a.js
```

Comment: Please don't change your questions after they have been answered. as it invalidates the answers you've received. It can even make those answers wrong, and adversely affect the reputation of those who answered. It is fine to add additional information, but it is better to create a new post and ask it there. I've edited your question and extended my answer this time but please take care in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The output in the file should be `at`. Can anyone suggest a way this can be done?

Remove the space between `a` and `%_a%`:

```
@echo off
setlocal 
set /p _a="Enter :"
echo a%_a% >a.js
endlocal
```

Example output:

```
F:\test>test
Enter :t

F:\test>type a.js
at
```

If you also want to remove the space **after** `at` then remove the space between `%_a%` and `>`:

```
@echo off
setlocal 
set /p _a="Enter :"
echo a%_a%>a.js
endlocal
```

---

#### My problem was that I needed to put the variable after the character `!`.

You need to escape the `!` using `^` as it is a character that has special meaning to `cmd`.

```
@echo off
setlocal 
set /p _a="Enter :"
echo a^!%_a% >a.js
endlocal
```

Example output:

```
F:\test>test
Enter :t

F:\test>type a.js
a!t
```

F:\test>

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [Quotes, Escape Characters, Delimiters - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)

Comment: I have a problem with this being too simple, so I suspect an XY question. Maybe your answer will find it out, so I deleted mine.

Comment: Indeed. Question was not specific enough. Got there in the end.